# Trying to create pointer to list element

Tags: c#, arrays, list, pointers, memory

I've got a List of RectangleF. I have a non-static class, which needs to have a reference to an element from this list.
I'm trying to use a pointer:

```
Item f = new Item();
unsafe
{
    f.linkedCollider = &Collisions.items.Last();
}
```

However, this arises a compiler error:

> Cannot take the adress of a given expression

Is there any way to go around this?

Comment: If you want to be able to hold onto references to the items in the list, then have a list of reference types, not value types.  Using pointers isn't going to lead to a productive solution.  And that's assuming you need a reference to the item to begin with, which you may not.

Comment: Using pointers is an extraordinarily bad idea.  Make a class that looks just like `RectangleF`, and use reference semantics.

Comment: You can use C# 7.0 ref returns. But maybe you should explain the problem you are trying to solve, looks like an xy problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to go around this: unlike its counterparts in C and C++, the address-of operator `&` in C# is very restrictive: [it can be applied only to variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/how-to-obtain-the-address-of-a-variable):

> The address-of operator can only be applied to a variable. If the variable is a moveable variable, you can use the `fixed` statement to temporarily fix the variable before obtaining its address.

You get the error message because method call is not a variable.

Since C# references behave in ways similar to smart pointers without requiring the pointer syntax, you can avoid pointers in most situations that require indirection.